# Xcode merging couldn't be performed - Tree conflicts

Tags: xcode, git, merge, branch, git-merge

I am currently working on a project in Xcode and I am using a local git repository for version control (note: I am working alone, not in a team). Lately I have developed a new feature in a new branch, let's call it `new-feature`. Now that it's finished I wanted to merge the `new-feature` branch into the master but Xcode throws this error:

[image]

The files `CircleButton.swift` and `EntrySelection.swift` are files I added to the project while being on the `new-feature` branch.

How can I solve this Problem?

I have read a lot about Xcode and Git but I didn't understand it all. I would be very grateful for a solution for my problem with a corresponding explanation for me to understand.

Comment: This problem appears to be Xcode specific. Git will declare a conflict and drop you to the command line and let you sort it out. Find Xcode's command line, perhaps.

Comment: So you suggest to manually merge my branch into master in the Terminal?

Comment: That should work, provided that either (a) there's some way to tell Xcode: "hey, I did stuff when you weren't looking, you'd better go look again." or (b) Xcode is smart enough to notice that you did stuff when it wasn't looking, and it had better go look again.

Comment: Thanks I merged the `new-feature` branch with SourceTree into the master and Xcode accepted it. Worked all fine